# Feature Request: Migrate in-progress answers too

Tags: feature-request, answers, migration

I was just answering a question on SO when I saw "Question closed.  No more answers will be accepted."  as soon as I finished my answer!  I went back to the question and discovered it was migrated to P.SE.  I followed the question there and ended up having to write my answer all over again!

**Feature request**: If a question is just *migrated*, leave the "Post Answer" button active and have it just post the answer to the destination site.

Comment: Why the downvote?  What's wrong with this?

Comment: Down-votes on meta mean "I don't agree with this idea" as well as "this question is unclear or not useful".

Comment: Nice, if easily implemented. If not, then I guess users should somehow be taught/told/suggested to copy their answer when posting fails — so then they should somehow be aware about the possibility of migration. (Not expecting that, I can see how you discarded your own answer there. But I guess it won't happen *to you* again?)

Comment: @ChrisF: I meant more like: "Why don't you agree with this?"

Comment: @John - OK. I wasn't sure.

Comment: Also note: it's been covered before, but if you spend more than about five minutes on an answer, just <ctrl><a> <ctrl><c> the textbox and put it on your clipboard for the two seconds or so it takes to submit so you don't get burnt when there's an error and you lose your five minutes or so